# Java: Drawing a Star from a Polygon Circle w/Point Connections

Tags: java, loops, casting, drawing, trigonometry

So, I have been working on this program for drawing a star from a circle created using `g.fillPolygon(int, int, int)`. I was intially having issues with creating an entire circle, but changed `double angle = (i * 360) to (i * 720)` to fix that (may be a band-aid fix, not sure yet). Now I'm in the process of attempting to connect all the points together (as shown in the "Target Output" section).

Note: I believe that the labeling of the points shown in the modification section was not done wih Java.

My Code: (Where I'm at right now)

```
import java.awt.*;

public class StarSampler {

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(500, 500);
           Graphics2D g = panel.getGraphics();
           g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

           fillStar(g, 250, 250, 150, 50, .7);
       }

       public static void fillStar(Graphics2D g, int ctrX, int ctrY, int radius, int nPoints, double spikiness)
       {
           double xDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];
           double yDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];
           int xPoint[] = new int[100]; 
           int yPoint[] = new int[100];

           for (int i = 0; i < 2*nPoints; i++)
           {
             double iRadius = (i % 2 == 0) ? radius : (radius * spikiness);
             double angle = (i * 720.0) / (2*nPoints);

             xDouble[i] = ctrX + iRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
             yDouble[i] = ctrY + iRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));

           for (int j = 0; j < nPoints; j++) // Casts for ints and doubles
           {
               xPoint[j] = (int) xDouble[j];
               yPoint[j] = (int) yDouble[j];
           }
           }
           g.fillPolygon(xPoint, yPoint, nPoints); // Creates polygon but 
       }
}
```

My Code's Output:

[image: Bad Star Drawing]

Target Output (What I'm generally aiming for, not both together):

[image: Good Star Drawing]

Comment: you have to keep drawing it.so override paintcomponent on jpanel.

Comment: if you want to access them declare them outside of for loops.since they are arrays you have to decide the length when you create them. `int xPoint[] = new int[length]; int yPoint[] = new int[length];`

Comment: So I overlooked the spikiness (changed fillStar(g, 250, 250, 100, 36, 1); to fillStar(g, 250, 250, 100, 36, .7);) but I am wondering why I am only getting half a circle or so?

Comment: are you sure this algorithm is right ?

Comment: I don't understand why/how I would have to override paintcomponent on jpanel :/

Comment: minimize and maximize

Comment: I feel pretty confident in the trig aspect, I am completely stumped on the half circle issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128315/discussion-between-aramza-and-fast-snail).

Comment: can you post a runnable code example.so we can test without creating our own classes

Comment: "I don't understand why/how I would have to override paintcomponent on jpanel ": because thats the usuall talking point - they cant live without repeating it